# ansible copy over balanced hosts

Tags: ansible

Ansible question here.

I did build a play with a template for a vhost (ssl and non ssl). This vHost will be use in DEV, QUAL and Production server.

I have a variable file with variables for each env. However, in production, I have 2 servers, with, obviously, 2 different ip.

How do I manage to have the same template with the 2 variables set to be pushed on each server with specific set of theses variables.

I am sure it is easy, I just can't wrap my mind around it.

Thanks.

p.s: Sorry for my bad english writing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess I was tired.

In my DEV and QUAL, I stated my variables in a group manner, but what I really needed was to split my variables by host.

I suppose the pease of a quiet home is a good thing.